# Validation with setter when creating object with constructor through method

Tags: c#, methods, constructor, setter

I have an object of Person that is created with a method, inside the method i use my constructor to create the object. I have some validation for the gender in my setter, but I can't see how i make it use my setter?

```
class Person
    {
        public string name;
        public int age;
        private string gender;
        private static List<Person> Personlist = new List<Person>();

        public Person(string _name, int _age, string _gender)
        {
            this.name = _name;
            this.age = _age;
            this.Gender = _gender;

        }

        public string Gender
        {

            get { return gender; }
            set
            {
                //value = de doorgegeven data
                if (value == "m" || value == "v")
                {
                    gender = value;
                }else
                {
                    gender = "Error: not a valid gender!";
                }
            }
        }
        public static void addPerson(string name, int age, string _gender){
            Personlist.Add(new Person(name, age, _gender));
        }
```

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Geef de naam van de persoon: ");
            var name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Geef de leeftijd van de persoon: ");
            var age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Geef het geslacht van de persoon [MOET 'v' OF 'm' ZIJN]: ");
            var gender = Console.ReadLine();



            Person.addPerson(name, age, gender);
            Person.speek(name, age, gender);

        }
    }
```

Comment: If gender was an Enum, you would not have to validate it (or set the property to a error message).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like duplicate of [C# add validation on a setter method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127290/c-sharp-add-validation-on-a-setter-method)

You have added complexity of initializing the property through constructor, which again isnt a standard design practice. There are certain constructs you can put in implementation because compiler can not stop you from doing it, however it does not mean you should do it.

Also worth reading about best practices in c# for constructor initializations - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/51062/constructor-parameter-validation-in-c-best-practices

I am updating the answer to include code example as below -

```
//Independent storage, not part of Person class.
private static List<Person> PersonList = new List<Person>();

static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Geef de naam van de persoon: ");
    var name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Geef de leeftijd van de persoon: ");
    var age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Geef het geslacht van de persoon [MOET 'v' OF 'm' ZIJN]: ");
    var gender = Console.ReadLine();

    //PersonList.Add(new Person("Person1", 25, "M"));
    PersonList.Add(new Person(name, age, gender));

    var p = PersonList[0];
    if(p.IsPersonModelStateValid == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Person state is valid");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Person state is invalid");
    }
    p.PrintPerson();
    Console.Error.WriteLine("Done!");
}
```

And the Person class is being refactored to as below -

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BSearch
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string name;
        public int age;
        private string gender;
        private bool isPersonStateValid;


        public Person(string _name, int _age, string _gender)
        {
            isPersonStateValid = true;
            this.name = _name;
            this.age = _age;
            this.Gender = _gender;
        }

        public string Gender
        {

            get { return gender; }
            set
            {
                //value = de doorgegeven data
                if (value == "m" || value == "v")
                {
                    gender = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    gender = "Error: not a valid gender!";
                    isPersonStateValid = false;
                }
            }
        }

        public bool IsPersonModelStateValid
        {
            get { return isPersonStateValid;}
            private set { isPersonStateValid = value; }
        }

        /*public static void addPerson(string name, int age, string _gender)
        {
            Personlist.Add(new Person(name, age, _gender));
        }*/

        public static void Speak(string name, int age, string _gender)
        {
            //TODO : The logic to make the person speak goes in here.
        }

        public void PrintPerson()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("name : " + this.name);
            Console.WriteLine("age : " + this.age);
            Console.WriteLine("gender : " + this.gender);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what you are saying is that i should not use the constructor to set the value of gender? or do you mean to not use the constructor at all? sorry verry new with this.

Comment: Avoid using constructor to run any complex logic that would leave your object in incomplete state. If you cant escape that, then use a flag or property to indicate the problem. Refer to ModelState.IsValid in asp.net where model initialization is beyond framework's realms but it provides a way to check if the model is in valid state. Most important : Do not throw any exceptions from constructor or initialiser that is being called from constructor. That is a recipe for disaster in terms of semantics.

Comment: But i don't get where it goes wrong: i'll explain, it goes from Person.addPerson -> Personlist.add -> Person constructor -> Gender setter. right?

Comment: I think the aspects of program should be separated in layers. For example storage in one layer, validation in another and user interaction in another. I cant paste code here since comments are restricted to limited character but pasting another answer below.