# How to use if condition within a property setter

Tags: c#

If null value is assigned to SettingCode, I want the value to instead be set to "" or empty string.

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
[StringLength(20)]
public string SettingCode { get; set; }
```

Comment: Did you even try anything? getters and setters are nothing but methods, so you can ady code there. However this assumes a body for each. Auto-properties hide that body away from you. See here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127290/c-sharp-add-validation-on-a-setter-method

Comment: You just need to manually implement the `set` and `get` methods.

Comment: Use a computed property.

Comment: It´s even mentioned in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are using an OR/M to feed this property. So you have on the DB  a nullable field, and you just don't want null in the code. This usually is not a good idea, since it will possibly lead to other problems while you persist back the data.
However, if this is the case, and you want to do it, use a backing field:

```
string settingCode;

[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
[StringLength(20)]
public string SettingCode { get {return settingCode??"";} set { settingCode=value; } }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is as simple as declaring a local variable to hold the value and implementing some code in `set`:

```
private string _settingCode;

[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
[StringLength(20)]
public string SettingCode
{
    get { return _settingCode; }
    set
    {
        _settingCode = value == null ? string.Empty : value;
    }
}
```

Comment: this return null if no one is setting the value, so there is a risk on reading a null.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a property + field to achieve that instead of an auto-implemented property :

```
private string _settingCode;

[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
[StringLength(20)]
public string SettingCode
{
    get { return _settingCode; }
    set { _settingCode = value?? string.Empty; }
}
```